# Could anyone explain the meaning of this shell statement?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am confused with following shell statement.

```
 export changeset=`hg parents | awk -F: '/^changeset:/ { print $2 }' | sed -e 's/ //g' -e 1q`
```

How does it work?

Thanks

Comment: With which part are you confused? Have you tried breaking it down into its component parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command does the following :-

- `hg parents` runs the mercurial command parents
- `awk -F: '/^changeset:/ { print $2 }'` starts awk reading its input and for any line that begins with changeset it prints the second field on the line (fields are separated by : )
- `sed -e 's/ //g' -e 1q` ` reads all of its input, removes spaces and prints the first line
- `export changeset=` Takes everything between the backticks runs this as a sequence of commands and assigns the result to the variable changeset.

The pipe symbol joins the commands together causing the standard output(STDOUT) of one program to become the standard input(STDIN) of another.

So in summary, after execution the variable changeset will contain the second field from the first line of the `hg parents` command that began with changeset.

Answer (score 1):

[Steve Weet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151237/could-anyone-explain-the-meaning-of-this-shell-statement/6151397#6151397) explains what's going on. Your pipeline can be simplified though. In your awk statement, because your delimeter is `:`, you can say `awk -F: '$1 == "changeset" {print $2}'`. Also, because awk and sed have many overlapping functions, you can write (all on one line if you prefer):

```
export changeset=$(
  hg parents | 
  awk -F: '$1 == "changeset" {gsub(/ /, "", $2); print $2; exit}'
)
```